# How to rename a state

Tags: azure-devops

How can I rename a state?
The `Name` field is **not editable**.
The state is already used by a lot of Tasks and User Stories.

Or is there any whay to add a new state and update all Tasks/User Stories to the new state at once?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit the `State` name in Azure DevOps. you can create your own state and use it instead of other state, in the state screen you have `+ New State` button, just click it and add the new state (after you created the state you **can't** change his name!).

If you want to move current work items to the new state, you can create a query that returns the work items, then mark all and edit to the new state.